# Trouble when using data in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, sqoop

I have ingested data using sqoop in hdfs , however my data contains comma ',' in single columns. when I am using the same data in spark then it is taking each comma as separator. what can I do to change these comma's?

suppose if you have xyz column inside I have a,b,c in first line and cd in second line then what I can do to avoid these comma's?

Comment: Can you explain what file format you are using? Assuming you are using csv, then one of the options is sep. If you also provide the code I can try to help

Comment: I am not using csv file . the file is in my database. which code you are talking about

Comment: how are you reading the file into spark? can you provide the code?

Comment: It would be better if you can add some data sample. A hunch says that your data export isn't correct. When you export data into a CSV and in a field (or column) your data contains a comma, it should be enclosed with quote or double quotes.

Comment: 42805,Bluesnap Payment Services Limited MID 0069,75014641,1,1,Bluesnap Payment Services Limited (UK),48372,71,1,3,2016-01-31 16:00:00.0,null,0,0.00,0.00,2,0,0,Pymt Prcd by BLUESNAP,true,www.bluesnap.com,594,global payment processing,840,3000000.00,50.00,1000.00,1,349,5009569,null,true,true,false,false,1,Terry.Monteith@bluesnap.com;Alona.shkolnik@bluesnap.com;Karin.biberstain@bluesnap.com;Michael.rubenhuk@bluesnap.com;Shay.sasson@bluesnap.com;Faouzi.kassab@bluesnap.com;

Comment: data looks like this shown above, and i don't have the spark code because I am only responsible for data ingestion.

Comment: I may not be understanding the question properly. what exactly are you trying to do? I thought you have files you are moving to hdfs and you want to read them in spark?. If so, what is the file format of the files? a text file with ',' as separator? if so, how is the escaping defined in your file format?

Comment: there is a table in MS SQL and I have imported that table in hdfs using sqoop.  But when my colleague trying to use it in spark he is getting issues because of comma. what I need to do is change this delimiter and aging ingest the data.

Comment: My question is can I use some thing to change this comma using sqoop

Comment: When you use sqoop, you choose the target file format. What format did you use? text? If you use something like avro, it would probably make the life of the spark side a lot easier.

Comment: I have not used target file format. but can you tell me if I have ingested data without any fied termination then is it by default takes comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While importing data in text format,  default field delimiter is comma(`,`). Since your data contains comma, change field delimiter.

Use `--fields-terminated-by <char>` in your sqoop import command.

Answer (score 0):

You might find these commands useful: 
 `--hive_drop-import-delims` or `--hive-delims-replacement`

[More info here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html)